# Is there a way to capture HTTP requests from an installed Play Store app?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, https

I'm developing a search aggregator service so I'd like to get the endpoint of some of the stores that, currently, doesn't expose their API. So I'd like to now if there's a way to do this with my cellphone.

Comment: Use a rooted device with Magisk for sniffing and a PC with a proxy like mitmproxy, Fiddler, Charles... On the device you can install the proxy as system certificate or alternatively use https unpinned und trusting solutions like frida/objection or simply the edXposed module + trustMeAlready module.

Comment: This might be weird, but sometimes submitting the APK to Virus Total may reveal some URLs as "Interesting Strings" (e.g. [the analysis of a random APK](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/f8310923d34e3bf0f3959e26522421f5b48142a38c953ce4667cd1cb44b24fc5/details)).

Comment: Sure solution can be an out-of-android one: install a https eavesdropping proxy. It requires a root certificate, that you should install into your android, somehow. Well, some apps, if they really want to, will be able to detect that you eavesdrop them and stop communicating on this reason, but it won't happen too often.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it on your phone alone. I use [HttpCanary App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.guoshi.httpcanary&hl=en_IN&gl=US) with root access. It works without root as well but only a few apps that don't use certificate pinning.

Comment: App is not available (anymore) and doesn't seem to be maintained since 2019 on GitHub.